# Comment traduire « save the date » en français ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions

Il existe dans les pays anglophones une coutume qui a tendance à se répandre, consistant à réaliser un faire-part simplifié dont le but est de rappeler la date de l'évènement. Ces minis faire-parts portent l'inscription **« save the date »**.

J'aimerais trouver une expression française qui puisse se substituer à l'expression anglaise *sans être forcément une traduction littérale* mais restant proche de la signification originale.

Merci d'avance pour votre aide.

Comment: Inscrivez la date dans votre agenda. /  À noter dans votre agenda.

Comment: Rappel : [Nom de l’événement], [Date] https://www.liveagent.fr/modeles-email/e-mails-de-rappel-pour-les-evenements/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> À vos agendas!

Ce n'est ni particulièrement formel, ni familier. Cette formule devrait convenir assez bien à un petit message simple, sans prendre trop de place.

Une petite recherche sur Internet montre que c'est utilisé fréquemment pour les annonces de tous types d’évènements, que ce soit par des particuliers, des compagnies ou des institutions.

Answer (score 5):

Souvent, en parlant d'un événement spécial, qui vient de se produire, on va dire qu'il «faut le marquer sur le calendrier», pour s'en rappeler. La même expression est utilisée pour parler d'un événement prévu, par exemple: «Marque ça sur le calendrier, il faudrait pas qu'on oublie.» C'est utilisé au Québec, je ne sais pas si ça l'est ailleurs.

Answer (score 4):

Ne prévois/prévoyez rien d'autre le [insert a date or day of the week here]

Answer (score 3):

> N'oubliez pas de l'inscrire dans votre agenda !

Cela semble être une formulation convenable pour un faire-part qui conserve suffisamment le sens de l'expression anglaise. Certes, la formulation n'est pas aussi concise, mais peut-être un mini faire-part contient-il assez de place pour ces neuf petits mots ?

Answer (score 3):

- *Mets/mettez une croix dans ton/votre calendrier (ou agenda)*
- *Note(z) le (bien) dans ton/votre calendrier*

Answer (score 2):

Je rajouterais encore comme proposition:

> Réservez la date!
>
> Merci de réserver la date.

Answer (score 1):

Pour faire court, je marquerais juste cette phrase suivie d'un smiley : "on compte sur vous" =)

Answer (score 1):

Dans la communauté francophone des blogs de mariage, on voit également souvent :

> Retenez la date

Answer (score 1):

> Notez la date !

ou

> Réservez la date !

Answer (score 0):

Je pense que j'ai entendu « Rendez-vous libre le … », mais je n'ai pas réussi à trouver un exemple.

Peut-être il est préférable d'utiliser un formulaire d'invitation plus français ?

Answer (score 0):

Pourquoi pas "... venez le jour J, .... *Souvenez-vous en*!"

Answer (score 0):

Et pourquoi pas : "Tous à vos agendas"

Comment: C'est une traduction envisageable pour *save the date*, mais pas sur un mini faire-part.

Answer (score 0):

*Retenez la date* est plus convenable en français comme en anglais.
**N'oubliez pas cette date** aussi passe si bien.

Answer (score 0):

Excellentes idées ci-dessus !

Pour ma part, je proposerais :

> Date à retenir (plus formel)

ou

> À bloquer ! (plus familier).